# Compare two tables in VBA and paste data into a third one

Tags: vba, excel, copy, comparison

I'm working since two weeks on a mini project and now, I'm stuck. I've tried many things before coming here and I hope to get some help.

I've two tables and 3 sheets ("PT" = worhskeets1 with the first table, "PI" = Worksheet2 with the second table, and "Comparison", the third worksheets used to compare the data from table 1 and table 2.

First and this works, when I copy the data in Cells(1, "A") in the first worksheets it automatically sort the values. Same on Worksheets 2.

In order to help you to understand, each table has "Codes" to which in a column besides an amount is associated (amount in EUR, USD, etc).
The problem is that codes can repeat in each column for both tables.

In the ideal scenario, when the two tables exactly matches (same length), I made a vlookup and it didn't worked. For the repeating codes, it took only the first "matchable" corresponding amount.
Then I tried to use the combo INDEX & MATCH. It worked.
I tried also to vlookup by making the "look up array" variable: as the codes are the same, I made a vlookup on each lines, one by one. Not very effective but as I won't have more than 50 rows it worked. The code looks like:

```
Dim wsi As Worksheet
Dim wst As Worksheet
Dim counter As Integer
Dim NonVideLondon As Integer
Set wsi = Worksheets("PI")
Set wst = Worksheets("PT")

NonVideLondon = wst.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
counter = 1
For i = 1 To NonVideLondon
LookupCode = Cells(i, "C") 'The codes from Table2

Cellnum = Application.VLookup(LookupCode, wsi.Range("C" & counter & ":C" &NonVideLondon), 1, False)

If IsError(Cellnum) Then
    Cells(i, "B") = "" 'Compared to the codes of table2
Else
    Cells(i, "B") = Cellnum
    counter = counter +1 
End If

Next i
```

(I apologize for the approximation of the code)

The issue is when Table 1 length > Table 2 Length and opposite.
Here I really don't know how to do.

On the sheet "Comparison" there are then 4 columns:

**CodePI**(Col B.) **CodePT**(Col C.)  **AmountPI**(Col. D)  **AmountPT**(Col. E)

In Col A there are buttons to clear all the sheets and to "Verify". It's a module done to check the length of table and launch a macro if table 1 > table 2 and another if Table 2 > Table 1.

When I do a vlookup, line by line (again, not very effective) when the two tables matched, this works and the comparison was correctly done.

I also tried the .FindMethod:

```
StrFind = Cells(j, "B")
Set fRng = Worksheets("PI").Range("C2:C50").Cells(Worksheets("PI").Range("C2:C50").Cells.Count)

 For i = Application.CountIf(Worksheets("PI").Range("C2:C50"), StrFind) To 1 Step -1
     Set fRng = Worksheets("PI").Range("C2:C50").Cells.Find(What:=StrFind, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                               After:=fRng, _
                               MatchCase:=True)

       If Not fRng Is Nothing Then
          With Worksheets("Comparison")
              .Cells(fRng.Row, "S") = fRng.Value
          End With
      End If
    Next i



Next j
```

But I'm always failing at having a "correct comparison table" for all situations (Table1 = Table2, new codes, Table 1 > Table 2 and Table 2 > Table 1). Oh the reason why I'm using a comparison table, is that the amounts can something perfectly match, sometimes change for a few amounts ( < 1). Then we **cannot** simply copy the amounts.

I've made another codes to "see the differences" (and it works when two tables are identical in length):

```
If Cells(i, "C") = Cells(i, "B").Value Then Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) _
Else: Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10) 'FOR CODES

If Cells(i, "E").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value Then Cells(i, "D").Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) _
Else: If Cells(i, "E").Value < Cells(i, "D").Value + 1 And Cells(i, "E").Value > Cells(i, "D").Value - 1 Then _
    Cells(i, "D").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 226, 133) _
    Else: Cells(i, "D").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10) ' FOR AMOUNTS
```

Now I think:

If table1 > table 2 then takes the data for codes and amount of table 1 and comparing them to table2. If there is a match (based on the position of the tables) then in the comparison sheet we will have in first column all the data from the longest table. Same for the amount (quite easy here, we only need to copy from the longest table to the comparison).

If there are codes in the second table that match the first one, how to make the correspondence? I mean if Table 1 > Table 2 all the date from Table1 would be "simply copied" but for the matching in Table2, how to make on the corresponding line of Table 1 (in WS comparison), the correct value of table 2 (code & amounts)?

I've also thought about adding a blank row in the shorter table every time a code is different in order to create a correspondence in table length (as the two tables are sorted by the values in corresponding sheets when users copy/paste data). It fails every time a "new code" is detected (or not found or not present):

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
ReDim Arr(1 To 30)

NonVideAddLondon = Worksheets("Paste Transcom").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To NonVideAddLondon

If Cells(i, "B") = "" Then
Arr(i) = Cells(i, "B").Row
Worksheets("Paste Investec").Rows(Arr(i)).Insert shift:=xlDown
Else
End If

Next i
```

Comment: For your info, I also tried .Find Method but it always fail !

Comment: Thank you for editing ! If I can improve my english by doing so, it's benefical !

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to do it asap. At the moment, here are the values I can provide:

Table 1 in the first Worksheets:
Just for noticing, in the original file the col "Code" is in the second column and "Amount" is in the 9th column. The code is derivated from a "LEFT()" and a correspondance table like the code just below table.

```
**Code**    **Amount**
Global               432,716.19
UMA     636,091.76
OMG     832,665.69
OOG     1,032,708.57
GRA       1,033,648.22
GOI        1,133,131.21
UOP       1,632,661.28
USB        3,033,309.01
LLI           3,332,737.06
LLB         3,332,826.35
GAO      3,533,775.81
UEB        5,734,412.75
UEN       5,832,700.11
UBT        5,945,724.80
Global               7,732,277.37
GVG      10,233,260.23
Global               11,048,022.73
Global               11,133,733.34
CRF        15,033,064.72
GCO       21,534,664.66
UTE        32,292,495.22
CBN       47,034,495.48
GDD/SAB    49,048,029.01
GDD/SAB    49,555,274.28
WTA      84,098,108.27
WTA      93,735,464.00
WTL       115,093,086.44
```

The code is derived from a "Select Case Fundcode" which if LEFT(columnA, "3").

```
    Case "BAL"
    Cells(i, "B") = "Global"

    Case "ERR"
    Cells(i, "B") = "LOP"

    Case "MLE"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UEB"

    Case "114"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UTE"

    Case "UTT"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UBT"

    Case "AOO"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UEM"

    Case "AB1"
    Cells(i, "B") = "LLB"

    Case "CDD"
    Cells(i, "B") = "LLE"

    Case "FDD"
    Cells(i, "B") = "LLI"

    Case "130"
    Cells(i, "B") = "OOG"

    Case "IOF"
    Cells(i, "B") = "GAO"

    Case "119"
    Cells(i, "B") = "GDD/SAB"

    Case "GAC"
    Cells(i, "B") = "GVG"

    Case "IUN"
    Cells(i, "B") = "GOI"

    Case "H3D"
    Cells(i, "B") = "WTA"

    Case "LSF"
    Cells(i, "B") = "WTL"

    Case "132"
    Cells(i, "B") = "CBN"

    Case "129"
    Cells(i, "B") = "USB"

    Case "UMA"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UMA"

    Case "139"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UOP"

    Case "UHI"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UHI"

    Case "114"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UTE"

    Case "UTT"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UBT"

    Case "OMG"
    Cells(i, "B") = "OMG"

    Case "GRA"
    Cells(i, "B") = "GRA"

    Case "137"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UGB"

    Case "126"
    Cells(i, "B") = "UEN"

    Case "CRF"
    Cells(i, "B") = "CRF"

    Case "GCO"
    Cells(i, "B") = "GCO"


    Case Else
    Cells(i, "B") = "New"
    Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10)
    Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10)
```

End Select

For Table 2 in a second Worksheet:

```
OMG    832,665.69
OOG     1,032,708.57
GRA      1,033,648.22
GOI       1,133,131.21
UOP      1,632,661.28
LLI          3,332,737.06
LLB        3,332,826.35
GAO     3,533,775.61
UEB       5,734,413.01
UEN      5,832,700.11
UBT       5,945,724.80
Global                  7,732,277.37
GVG     10,233,260.23
Global                  11,048,022.73
Global                  11,133,733.34
CRF    15,033,064.72
GCO   21,534,664.66
UTE       32,292,495.39
CBN      47,034,495.44
GDD/SAB            49,555,274.32
WTA                  84,098,108.27
WTA     93,735,464.00
```

As I said previously when both columns size fits, the issue is quite easy to solve. But as soon as, like in this case, the size differs I don't know how to deal with it.

Here Table2 has 24 values while Table1 has 28. As you can see in both table there are several times the same code with different amount. Also the amounts can change a little bit (from few cents).

The idea is to create a third table like this one:

t1 = Table 1, t2 = Table 2

```
Code(t1) Code(t2) Amount(t1)   Amount(t2)
Global                          432,716.19
UMA                      636,091.76
OMG       OMG               832,665.69         832,665.69
OOG       OOG      1,032,708.57                  1,032,708.57
GRA         GRA        1,033,648.22       1,033,648.22
GOI          GOI        1,133,131.21       1,133,131.21
UOP         UOP        1,632,661.28        1,632,661.28
USB                         3,033,309.01
LLI             LLI    3,332,737.06                        3,332,737.06
LLB           LLB    3,332,826.35        3,332,826.35
GAO        GAO    3,533,775.81        3,533,775.61
UEB          UEB    5,734,412.75        5,734,413.01
UEN         UEN    5,832,700.11        5,832,700.11
UBT          UBT    5,945,724.80        5,945,724.80
Global    Global  7,732,277.37        7,732,277.37
GVG       GVG      10,233,260.23       10,233,260.23
Global    Global              11,048,022.73        11,048,022.73
Global    Global     11,133,733.34        11,133,733.34
CRF         CRF      15,033,064.72        15,033,064.72
GCO        GCO        21,534,664.66        21,534,664.66
UTE         UTE         32,292,495.22        32,292,495.39
CBN        CBN      47,034,495.48        47,034,495.44
GDD/SAB                   49,048,029.01
GDD/SAB    GDD/SAB 49,555,274.28        49,555,274.32
WTA      WTA        84,098,108.27        84,098,108.27
WTA      WTA        93,735,464.00        93,735,464.00
WTL       WTL        115,093,086.44        115,093,086.44
```

As you can see the first "Global" is not in the snd table but appears in first table. Hence Table1 size > Table2, it appears in col1 (Code(t1)) but not in Code(t2) as in this position of the table, the code doesn't appear. Same for the amount.

The amounts are all sorted before. So "normally" if bot sizes are identical, the amounts can be filled in table 3 easily.

The idea is to create a VBA function that fill in table 3 regarding the positions of the row in table1 (the longest) compared to the table2 (the lowest row). It should put the values from table2 in the corresponding row of table1 in a third table "the summary".

As you can see in table 2 the first "GLOBAL", "USB" and the first "GDD SAB" is not present. It's not present in table 3 neither but other global and GDD/SAB are. That's exaclty what I try to achieve; retrieve data from other table based on codes which may appears several times with different values.

May be it's not clear... It's hard to explain.